# cURL PHP + Google Speech

Tags: php, libcurl

Estou tentando elaborar um algoritmo em php para pegar um determinado arquivo .flac e , através do google speech retornar o texto gerado através do mesmo.

Segue abaixo o código:

```
$filename="good-morning-google";
$file_to_upload = array('myfile'=>'@'.$filename.'.flac');
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?output=json&lang=pt-BR&key=MINHAKEY");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("Content-Type: audio/x-flac; rate=44100"));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file_to_upload);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$result=curl_exec ($ch);
var_dump($result);
```

Não sei o que esta ocorrendo de errado que o retorno da var $result é igual a falso.

Comment: o  frame rate do arquivo "good-morning-google.flac" está realmente em 44100 hz conforme especificado em seu código ?

Comment: Estou realizando o teste de acordo com esse project no github https://github.com/rogerthomas84/php-speech-to-text ... Porem esta dando o mesmo erro.